# How do I create a generic DataContext factory?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, generics, datacontext

I'm building a generic `Repository<T>` class that supports Linq to SQL, and I'd like to use a factory pattern for the DataContext, because currently I have to pass the correct context to the constructor.

Does anybody know how to determine the correct DataContext type for `T`, where `T` is a Linq to Sql Table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not really need to.

Just take in a DataContext and you can access the tables using `GetTable<T>()`.

Comment: So what is the purpose of the FooDataContext class that gets generated? Is it just so you don't have to specify the type in a generic method?

Comment: No, the FooDataContext that gets generated also has properties that represent the table(s) in the database. That allows you to do something like myFooDataContext.MyTable....

Comment: Its purpose is exactly that. It allows you to use a meaningful name when using it and provides intellisense. If you look into the generated code, all those properties do is call GetTable<T>().

Comment: Keep in mind that if you do this, you'll lose any behaviour you might have implemented in the DataContext's partial OnXxx methods.